# How can I loop-insert incremental dates into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

How can I add rows to a table with only SQL that loops and increments a date e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (the_date) VALUES ('2013-04-13');
INSERT INTO my_table (the_date) VALUES ('2013-04-14');
INSERT INTO my_table (the_date) VALUES ('2013-04-15');
INSERT INTO my_table (the_date) VALUES ('2013-04-16');
...
```

I need to insert a row for every day from 2013-05-07 for the next e.g. 1000 days.

Comment: Your loop....you have to consider first the num of loop, then look for the last inserted id in that table and take that date....then in the loop you should sum 1 day to that date and make the insert ;) ....wich mysql extension are you using??

Comment: How many rows do you want to insert? Are there other columns in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will do it:-

```
INSERT INTO my_table (the_date)
SELECT ADDDATE('2013-04-13', INTERVAL SomeNumber DAY)
FROM (SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100+d.i*1000 AS SomeNumber FROM integers a, integers b, integers c, integers d) Sub1
WHERE SomeNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
```

Relies on a table called integers with a single column called i with 10 rows, values from 0 to 9.

The Between clause is just there so you can limit the range of numbers to add to the date

Comment: It is really, but it is a very useful and simple table (allows you to generate ranges of numbers as large as you like), plus means you can do what you want with a single SQL statement rather than looping through and doing many inserts. I have done a minor edit so it will cope with 1000 days (will cope with between 0 and 9999 days now with just a change to the BETWEEN clauses)

Comment: As an aside, you can avoid adding the extra table of integers. You can cross join against a sub query that returns the numbers 0 to 9. For example _(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)_ .

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$starDate = new DateTime('2013-05-07');

for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
  $consulta ="INSERT INTO my_table (the_date) VALUES ('".date_format($starDate, 'Y-m-d')."');";
  $starDate = date_add($starDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
  echo $consulta."</br>";
  //try somthing like mysqli_query($consulta);
}
```

With php and mysqli....you can do this with pure sql too ;)

I give you this way to do.

Saludos ;)